# Elasticsearch scroll API to retrieve all the documents in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

Use case is to retrieve all the documents in ES the fastest way. I have implemented ES - scroll API like below. Steps for the implementation is as follows.

1. Issue a scroll request and retrieve first 1000 documents.
2. Retrieve the scroll ID for the previous request and set in the API response so users can use it for next scroll request.
3. use the scroll Id and retrieve and next 1000 documents and set the new scroll Id for the subsequent calls.
4. Unfortunately, I am able to only retrieve the first 1000 documents and when I pass the scroll id to retrieve next 1000 I get zero results.

   public PageableDTO scanAndScroll(String apiVersion,String indexName,String indexType,String pageIndex,String scrollId)
       {

   ```
           try {

                   final TimeValue timeoutScroll = TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(30L);
                   SearchResponse scrollResp;

                   //If scroll id is passed to the API use it else use the scroll ID from the
                   //matchAllResponse
                   if (StringUtils.isEmpty(scrollId)) {
                           scrollResp =
                                   client.prepareSearch(indexName)
                                           .setTypes(indexType)
                                           .setFrom(Integer.valueOf(pageIndex)) // pageIndex should be 0 in normal usage!
                                           .setScroll(timeoutScroll)
                                           .setSize(1000)
                                           .execute()
                                           .actionGet();
                   }
                   else {
                           scrollResp =
                                   client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollId)
                                           .setScroll(timeoutScroll)
                                           .execute()
                                           .actionGet();
                   }

                   if (null != scrollResp)
                   {
                           for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
                                   result.add(hit.getSource());
                           }
                           Map<String, Object> scrollMapping = new HashMap<>();
                           scrollMapping.put("ScrollId", scrollResp.getScrollId());
                           result.add(scrollMapping);
                   }
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
           }

           pageableDTO.setTotalRecords(result.size());
           pageableDTO.setList(result);

           return pageableDTO;
   }
   ```

Comment: @Val can you help me this?

Comment: Does it work when you scroll using a simple curl command? How many results are you expecting?

Comment: @Val. It works if do the subsequent call inside a while loop. Problem is when I exit the code and try to access the next set of results using the previous active scroll Id it doesn't work. I will try the curl. I am expecting around 200k documents in total. 10000 per request.